# Problems with Confusion matrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

Im trying to run a confusion matrix between two lists to determine the Accuracy, Sensitivity, and Specificity. I have the two lists a and b with a collection of different variables (i.e. 0/0, 1/1, 0/1). Initially, I ran into the error Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels. and I was able to fix it by using a table in the confusion matrix but that lead to an error, Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type. I tried to compensate by instead using the union function(seen below) but still no luck. Im not sure what is necessarily wrong with the data?

```
predicted
   [1] "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/0" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" NA   
  [18] "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" NA    NA    NA    "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1"
  [35] "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" NA    "0/1" "0/1"
  [52] "0/1" "0/0" NA    "0/1" NA    "0/1" "1/1" NA    NA    "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" NA   
  [69] "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1"
  [86] "1/1" "0/0" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" NA    "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" NA   
 [103] "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" NA    NA    "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1"

reference
   [1] "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1"
  [18] "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1"
  [35] "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1"
  [52] "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1"
  [69] "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1"
  [86] "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1"
 [103] "0/1" "0/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "1/1" "1/1" "1/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1" "0/1"

 table(actual=a,predicted=b)
      predicted
actual       0/0  0/1  1/1
          3    0    0    0
   0/1    0  113 1992   28
   1/1    0    5   74 1473
> cm <- confusionMatrix(data = b, reference = a)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
> cm <- confusionMatrix(table(b, a))
Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type
> predicted <- ExomeC$GT.Imp.15
> reference <- ExomeC$GT.Exome
> 
> u <- union(predicted, reference)
> t <- table(factor(predicted, u), factor(reference, u))
> confusionMatrix(t)
Error in `[.default`(data, , pos) : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: What class are *predicted* and *reference*? The confusionMatrix function expects factors.

Comment: just checked they are both characters

Comment: You can coerce them with reference <- as.factor(reference)

Comment: And it looks like you're assuming the table function creates new objects a and b, but that's not correct (unless a and b were created somewhere before this code snippet)

Comment: Sorry yes, a and b are columns isolated from a larger table. I coerced them with reference and was brought up with an options menu, when I try to select an option the console brings up Browse[1]> and ends.   Like below                                                                                                      Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: confusionMatrix(t)
2: confusionMatrix.table(t)
3: data[, pos]
4: `[.table`(data, , pos)
5: NextMethod()                                                                                                           Selection: 2
Browse>

Comment: Do you get the expected output with: confusionMatrix(as.factor(predicted), as.factor(reference)) ?

Comment: I keep getting this prompt;

Comment: Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(pre), as.factor(ref)) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: confusionMatrix(as.factor(pre), as.factor(ref))
2: confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(pre), as.factor(ref))

Comment: Do you get identical output when you run levels(pre) and levels(ref) ?

Comment: Yes, the output leads to the ... Selection: 1
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240313/discussion-between-bill-obrien-and-robert-s).